# Add '/mobile' to url on mobile device

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to come up with an htaccess code that will allow me to redirect users on all mobile devices going to webpage that begins with `www.example.com/blog` or `example.com/blog` to specific page - pretty much the same link with the following extension: `/mobile`.

so that websites for mobile devices become:

```
www.example.com/blog -> www.example.com/blog/mobile

example.com/blog -> example.com/blog/mobile
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /$0/mobile [L,NC,R=302]
```

This is assuming you don't have a `.htaccess` inside `blog/` directory.

If you already have a `blog/.htaccess` then use this rule in `blog/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /blog/mobile [L,R=302]
```

---

If above header don't work then use `user agent` based checks:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /$0/mobile [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: How reliable are the `x-wap-profile` or `Profile` headers for detecting a "mobile device" supposed to be? None of my mobile devices appear to send either of these headers?

Comment: ok then 2nd option is to use `HTTP_USER_AGENT` conditions as in my edited answer.